# Отобразить файл html в окне PyQt5 (подойдет и файл pdf, если проще)

Tags: python, html, pyqt5, qt-designer, qwebengineview

Есть инструкция в формате файла **`.html`** и **`.pdf`**, нудно вывести в отдельное окно в программе содержимое любого из этих файлов, чтобы пользователь при вызове инструкции мог её прочитать.

В инструкции есть текст, таблицы и картинки. 
То что я написал, выводит чистое окно, подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1019, 593)


        self.webView = QWebEngineView(parent=Form)
        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 1021, 561))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle("ИНСТРУКЦИЯ")
        with open("///home/dev7/PycharmProjects/po-uvt/index.html", 'r') as f:
            html = f.read()
            self.webView.setHtml(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello PyQt5</h1>
    <h2>Hello PyQt5</h2>
    <h3>hello PyQt5</h3>
    <h4>hello PyQt5</h4>
    <h5>hello PyQt5</h5>
    <h6>Hello PyQt5</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

> void QWebEngineView::[**load**](https://%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20URL-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE.)(const QUrl &url)
>
> Загружает указанный URL-адрес и отображает его.

> QUrl QUrl::[**fromLocalFile**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qurl.html#fromLocalFile)(const QString &localFile)
>
> Возвращает QUrl-представление localFile, интерпретируемое как локальный файл. Эта функция принимает пути, разделенные косой чертой, а также собственный разделитель для этой платформы.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1019, 593)

        self.webView = QWebEngineView(parent=Form)
        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 1021, 561))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle("ИНСТРУКЦИЯ")
        '''
        with open("///home/dev7/PycharmProjects/po-uvt/index.html", 'r') as f:
            html = f.read()
            self.webView.setHtml(html)
        '''


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        file = "D:/_Qt/__Qt/q1502557_index.html"            # !!! +++
        self.webView.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file))  # !!! +++        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    '''
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    '''
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**q1502557_index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello PyQt5</h1>
    <h2>Hello PyQt5</h2>
    <h3>hello PyQt5</h3>
    <h4>hello PyQt5</h4>
    <h5>hello PyQt5</h5>
    <h6>Hello PyQt5</h6>
    <p style="margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; 
      margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; 
      text-indent:0px;">
      <img src="D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg" /> 
    </p>
    
    <table cellspacing="2" border="1" cellpadding="5" width="600">
      <tbody>
        <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr>
        <tr><td>item 0_0</td><td>item 0_1</td><td>item 0_2</td><td>item 0_3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 1_0</td><td>item 1_1</td><td>item 1_2</td><td>item 1_3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 2_0</td><td>item 2_1</td><td>item 2_2</td><td>item 2_3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 3_0</td><td>item 3_1</td><td>item 3_2</td><td>item 3_3</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>    

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, он для меня очень полезен, но еще оказалось в Ubuntu проблема с путями, но  справились.